# Joomla custom template parameter tab title

Tags: templates, configuration

I'm adding a new fieldset with custom params to my template:

```
<config>
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="advanced" addfieldpath="/templates/mytemp/fields">
            ...     
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset name="custom">
            ...
```

The name of that fieldset gets used for the Template-Tab as following:

```
COM_TEMPLATES_CUSTOM_FIELDSET_LABEL
```

In which language file (that needs to be installed with the template) can i insert that language constant?

`de-DE.tpl_mytemp.ini` and `de-DE.tpl_mytemp.sys.ini` is not working.

Comment: Your question appears to unresolved/abandoned and therefore "bumped" by the system.  Have you managed to resolve your issue? If Sharky's answer did the trick you can award the green tick or post your own answer.  All questions should progress to a system-recognized resolution.  Please let us know if there is more that we can help you with.

Answer (score 0):

First I suggest that you do not use language strings containing prefixes of other extensions. You can use your own language strings by adding `label` attribute to the fieldset:

```
<fieldset name="custom" label="TPL_MYTEMP_CUSTOM_FIELDSET_LABEL">
```

The file for template configuration strings is `de-DE.tpl_mytemp.ini`. Depending on your template setup it should be installed either in `language/de-DE` or `templates/mytemp/language/de-DE`. If the file is not loaded, make sure `mytemp` matches the value of `<name>` element in `templateDetails.xml` file. Neither should have `tpl_` prefix, apparently. When language files are loaded `tpl_` prefix is added automatically so in case you do have it in your template's name, the resulting file would end up being `de-DE.tpl_tpl_mytemp.ini`.

To further debug language issues enable `Debug Language` in `Global Configuration`. With this you'll see which language files are being loaded, which files are missing and if there's any errors.

Comment: All was done that way. The `COM_TEMPLATES_CUSTOM_FIELDSET_LABEL` gets displayed in the tab without me doing anything. Seams like this `<fieldset name="custom">`in the template XML gets parsed, but i don't understand why it's not taking my template name `mytemp` and thus my language constant.

Comment: It's not supposed to. If no label is present, it builds this: `COM_TEMPLATES_' . $name . '_FIELDSET_LABEL`, where `$name` is fieldset name.

Comment: Also make sure that your language file has been formatted correctly. If you forget a quote somewhere, or an equals = symbol, then Joomla will only show the language tag (and not the values from the language file).